# How to disable the length limitation of pasted text in VScode when word wrap is disabled?

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I paste a very long text, it will limit the end of the string with three dots, like so:

```
verylongtextverylongtextvxtverylongtextverylongtextverylongtext…
```

This does not happen if I enable word wrap, which I don't prefer to have enabled, especially when I am pasting huge content into the editor.

Answer (score 6):

Try this setting:

```
"editor.stopRenderingLineAfter": -1
```

see https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/7772#issuecomment-347174463

Vscode will dim the setting as `unknown` but it is supposed to work anyway - fortunately I can't test ;>} A limit was set for performance reasons so disabling it may have repercussions...

Comment: Thank you for sharing this solution, it worked for me. I cannot express how annoying is this behavior, and the fact that you cannot easily disable it.

Answer (score 1):

This behaviour is very confusing, but to clarify the problem - it is a rendering limitation in VS code. The full text has been pasted, so reformatting the document will render it correctly

Answer (score 0):

I got around this by pasting the raw data into notepad, saving as `whatever.txt` in my target directory, and then changing the filename to `whatever.json` in VSC. Worked like a charm.

Of course, this is fine for a one time solution, I'm not recommending it for routine practice.